# Is it possible to limit a user file upload to a specific file, not just file type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension

I have an application that requires a user to download a file then upload it to my server. It is a server that will scan an image for text, and output it.

I have made a Chrome extension that will do the part of saving the image, but I now need to control that upload to my server. this is where my problems arise.

I honestly didn't think the troubling part of this would be a simple file upload.

I tried just doing a XHR request to file://whatever.jpg by saving the download folder as the URL. I get CORS issues.

I've tried saving the image to a canvas and sending the base64 to my server to save, but I get tainted canvas issues.

I've also tried just setting up an input tag with a default value of the proper downloaded file. This does not seem to work either.

The only thing I can try is to save the name of the image, and test the file upload to the same names. But that feels really ugly to me.

Having to ask for a file input, then alert "no, not that one, click this one".
then submit it. Since the idea was to just insert a div below the images with the output after you click the extension button.

I also don't like the idea of them being able to rename a file to trick it.

Comment: To verify it's the same file, I'd compare [md5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5) of both copies.

Comment: Is there any reason that the user couldn't just supply the url of the image and your server would do the rest?

Comment: There are only two ways to gain access to the file system using JavaScript in the browser: 1) a `drop` event from a DnD operation with a file and 2) an `HTMLInputElement` submitted as part of a form. This all means that accessing that file **requires a user input** to accomplish.

Comment: @enhzflep - That is the correct solution here. Instead of workflow: 1) download file 2) upload file to server - this should be 1) get file download url 2) pass file download url to server 3) server retrieves file using file download url

Comment: Yes your workflow is biased, indeed just ask for the url. Now, how come you manage the file downloaded but don't have access to its content; or how come you can't send it to your server from your extension directly? Can you show what you use to grab the file content and save it currently?

Comment: In order for an extension to be able to read the file:// URL contents directly you need to explicitly enable file access on chrome://extensions details page for your extension, which will open up the entire local file system to the extension. Of course you'll need to add `<all_urls>` or `file://*/*` to manifest.json permissions, and access the file:// URL in your internal extension script such as the background script or a browserAction popup script - not a content script.